# Any good Sublime Text 3 Angular 2 Snippets and Code Completions?

Tags: angular, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I am looking for Sublime Text 3 Angular 2 Snippets and Code Completions.

I found John Papa's snippets for sublime text but it seems like it's deprecated and also not listed on `Install Packages` on my sublime. This used to be the [URL](https://github.com/pjlamb12/st3-ng2-snippets) but now it looks empty. Also the same with the official [packagecontrol website](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Angular%202%20Snippets%20%28John%20Papa%29), no readme etc.

Anybody has any suggestion for Sublime Text 3 Angular 2 Snippets and Code Completions? or how to install John Papa's package?

Comment: Why is it voted down?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/evanplaice/angular2-snippets

https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-sublime-package

check these packages if of any help for you...

Comment: I am trying angular2-snippets package. I see that as for now, we can only do manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I ended up doing it manually

1. In the command palette search for `Package Control: Add Repository` (Cmd+Shift+P)
2. In the input panel, insert the github path `https://github.com/evanplaice/angular2-snippets` (or anything else)
3. Install it using `Package Control: Install Package`